# Синтаксис запроса UPDATE

Tags: mysql, синтаксис, php, запрос, update

Прошу помощи с синтаксисом запроса UPDATE.

Есть таблица `system_contacts` с 22 полями. Пытаюсь обновить некоторые из них, получаю ошибку:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 'company_name' = 'rr', 'company_address' = '', 'company_person'' at line 2 in D:\data\contact_edit.php on line 23 Ошибка - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 'company_name' = 'rr', 'company_address' = '', 'company_person'' at line 2
```

Запрос в `contact_edit.php`:

```
  $query = "UPDATE system_contacts                
    SET (
    'company_name' =    '".$_POST["company_name"]."',
    'company_address' = '".$_POST["company_address"]."',
    'company_person' =  '".$_POST["company_person"]."',    
    'phone_1' =         '".$_POST["phone_1"]."',
    'phone_2' =         '".$_POST["phone_2"]."',
    'phone_3' =         '".$_POST["phone_3"]."',
    'phone_4' =         '".$_POST["phone_4"]."',
    'phone_5' =         '".$_POST["phone_5"]."',
    'work_time' =       '".$_POST["work_time"]."',
    'skype' =           '".$_POST["skype"]."',
    'site' =            '".$_POST["site"]."')
    WHERE 'id_position' = '45'
    ";

  $usr = mysql_query($query);                 // строка 23
  if(!$usr) exit ("Ошибка - ".mysql_error());
```

Перерыл всё, что мог. В чем может быть ошибка и где копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите скобки после слова `SET` и перед словом `WHERE`. У вас даже в сообщении ошибки это написано.

А еще, когда вы дебажите SQL и у вас возникают проблемы, то просто сделайте вывод SQL запроса на экран, скопируйте и попробуйте вставить его напрямую. Часто бывают лишние запятые, не те кавычки, апострофы вместо обратной кавычки в названиях полей. Куча синтаксических ошибок при ручном формировании запросов.

Upd: а еще у вас на лицо SQL инъекция, так как ваши данные из POST массива никак не обрабатываются, прочитайте про `prepared statements` и начните использовать PDO.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, скобки точно были лишние. (Хотя, вроде бы, и убирал их, а все равно что-то не работало). PDO буду изучать. Пока что от инъекции планирую защищаться с помощью:   

`$_POST["password"] = htmlentities( get_magic_quotes_gpc()?stripslashes($_POST["password"]):$_POST["password"])`

Это нормальное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, как Вы пишите, лучше не делать - гарантированный путь к sql инъекции. Собственно в данном случае Вы ее, похоже, и словили. Если любая из переменных в POST будет содержать одинарную кавычку, то запрос будет выглядеть не совсем так, как Вы думаете. Скорее всего, переменная `$_POST["company_address"]` содержит левое.

Что делать?

Первое - распечатайте значение переменной query, ее значение немного прояснит ситуацию. Также распечатайте `var_dump($_POST)`.

Второе - перейдите на использование [pdo](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php), и Ваши запросы будут чище, красивее и безопаснее.

Третье - если все-таки хочется писать по-старому, не забывайте экранировать строки, но это устаревшее, и для пхп не рекомендуют использовать этот способ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нормально ли использовать решение, хотя бы в качестве временного рабочего:
`$_POST["password"] = htmlentities( get_magic_quotes_gpc()?stripslashes($_POST["password"]):$_POST["password"])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Показываю решение, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится. Вначале свёл запрос к виду:

```
$query = "UPDATE `system_contacts`
SET `company_name` = '1'
WHERE `id_position` = '45' ";
```

Запрос прошел. Затем добавил значение $_POST

```
$query = "UPDATE `system_contacts`
SET `company_name` = '".$_POST["company_name"]."'
WHERE `id_position` = '45' ";
```

Запрос тоже прошёл без ошибок (это никак не отменяет сказанное в двух ответах выше о возможности инъекции, сейчас просто говорю о синтаксисе). После этого добавил все оставшиеся значения $_POST[...], всё работает.